# How To Slide Activities left and right in Android

Tags: android

I have to implement sliding method for my project. Can anyone share any link or example/Code to Slide the Activities Left and Right Not using the Flipper method, as it slides just the inside of Layout but not the complete Activities.

Comment: AFAIK you can't switch trough activities like trough **Fragments** in Viewpager

Answer (score 2):

This is what I am currently doing with my project:

```
public class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private final int NUM_PAGES;
private final String[] titles;
private final View[] views;

public CustomPagerAdapter(View[] views, String[] titles){
    super();
    this.NUM_PAGES = views.length;
    this.views = views;
    this.titles = titles;
}   

@Override
public int getCount(){
    return NUM_PAGES;       
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){
    return titles[position];
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(views[position]);
    return views[position];
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view) {
     ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((View) view);
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}

}
```

You pass to the constructor the views and the title of the views you want to slide.
To use this adapter you add:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center" 
            >

            <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top" 
                android:textColor="@color/title_strip_text_color"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@color/title_strip_background_color"/>
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

to your xml layout and then in the OnCreate of your Activity (or OnCreateView of your Fragment) you add the following lines:

```
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) edit_hero_fragment_layout.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
CustomPagerAdapter edit_hero_pager_adapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(views, titles);
viewPager.setAdapter(edit_hero_pager_adapter);
```

As already said you can't slide activities!